# Think good and it will be good

Tags: sources-mekorot

Does anyone know of a gemara or other maamar chazal  which says something along the lines of "think good and it will be good" ?

Comment: Its not a Gemara it comes from a famous Yiddishism - טראכט גוט וועט זיין גוט

Comment: It is apparently ascribed to the third Lubavitcher Rebbe - the Tzemach Tzedek

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/88833/jewish/Chapter-12-A-Lightning-Rod-To-The-Spiritual-Realms.htm#footnoteRef11a88833 -  
See Sefer HaSichos 5687, p. 113 and sources cited there; explained in Likkutei Sichos, Parshas Shemos 5751.

Comment: *Gam zu letovah*, in the Talmud?

Comment: The Chazon Ish (Emunah U'bitachon 2:1) posits, that "thinking good" will not always produce the outcome that you desire. https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14370&st=&pgnum=15

Comment: @IsraelReader The Chazon Ish is discussing what constitutes bitachon, and says that it's not bitachon to believe that the outcome will definitely be favorable. It's possible to both accept his definition of bitachon and also in addition believe that having positive thoughts about the future can influence the outcome.

Comment: The logical inference from this statement would be that which the Gemara says אל תפתח את הפה לשטן

Comment: @CuriousYid שֹׁמֵר פִּיו וּלְשׁוֹנוֹ שֹׁמֵר מִצָּרוֹת נַפְשׁוֹ.

Comment: @Jay I understand that the expression, "think good, and it will be good", implies that thinking "good" has the magical POWER to make that "good" happen, which can lead the person to believe, that he, a puny human being, is in control, and that man has the ability to assure himself of a good outcome ("it WILL be good"). That notion is even more outrageous than the erroneous Bitachon that the Chazon Ish is decrying, which merely posits that one must believe that the outcome will definitely be favorable, even though the person may be aware that he actually has no way of controlling the outcome.

Comment: @IsraelReader Just like "tie your laces so you don't trip" implies that a puny human has the magical ability to control his destiny by merely tying a knot.

Comment: @IsraelReader i think we need to make a distinction between something potentially affecting an outcome vs something absolutely guaranteeing an outcome. I understand this concept the first way.

Comment: @shmosel "Think good, and it will be good". The correct analogy would be more like: "Tie your laces, and you won't trip". That is a ludicrous assurance, since there can be many potential causes for a person to trip; of which, only one of them is prevented by tying your laces.

Comment: @Jay In this context, the word "will", is a modal verb that expresses **confident predictions**, as in ""good things will happen". The modal verb that expresses, "potentially affecting an outcome", is "*can*". Hence, the saying would need to be changed to: "Thinking good, can make it good".

Comment: @IsraelReader i think its meant to be taken in the same vein as any segulah, including those mentioned in Chazal - those are also worded as confident predictions, but they are not meant to be taken as guarantees. I see what you're saying regarding the literal wording which can be understood as a guarantee, but I just don't think that's how it was intended. If anyone understands it as a guarantee, I agree with you that that's a big mistake. There are no guarantees. Good Shabbos and gmar chasimah tovah.

Comment: @Jay The problem is, that so far, no one has come up with a reference to a gemara or other maamar chazal, that supports such an alleged "segulah".